# error in msgsnd - msgrcv, I can't view the second string sent

Tags: c, fork, ipc

Hi (sorry for my bad English), I'm trying to practice Linux to manipulate message queues in IPC.
I have created a program that allows one process (child 1) to send the message in the queue, while the other process (child 2) reads that message.
this message is defined as a structure composed of two strings (str1 and str2) and a type (long).
The goal that I want to realize and read the two strings but the result is that the program in the reads only one.
Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct{
    long int type;
    char str1[255];
    char str2[255];
}msg;

void sender(int fd_msg){
    msg message;
    char *string1 = "Hello";
    char *string2 = "World"; 

    strcpy(message.str1,string1);
    strcpy(message.str2,string2);

    message.type = 1;
    if(msgsnd(fd_msg,&message,strlen(message.str1)+1,0) == -1){
        printf("Error sending message at message 1 queue %d --> %s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
        return;
    }

    message.type = 2;
    if(msgsnd(fd_msg,&message,strlen(message.str2)+1,0) == -1){
        printf("Error sending message at message 2 queue %d --> %s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
        return;
    }

    if(printf("Message sent at the queue: %s -- %s\n",message.str1,message.str2) < 0){
        printf("Error printing sent messages %d --> %s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
        msgctl(fd_msg,IPC_RMID,NULL);           
        return; 
    }
    return;
}

void receiver(int fd_msg){
    msg message;
    char string1[255];
    char string2[255];
    
    sleep(1);
    if(msgrcv(fd_msg,&message,sizeof(message)-sizeof(long int),1,0) == -1){
        printf("error reiceiving message type 1 %d --> %s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
        return;

    }
    if(msgrcv(fd_msg,&message,sizeof(message)-sizeof(long int),2 ,0) == -1){
        printf("error reiceiving message type2 %d --> %s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
        return;
    }   

    if(printf("Message reiceved! : %s -- %s\n",message.str1,message.str2) < 0){
        printf("Error printing received message %d --> %s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
        msgctl(fd_msg,IPC_RMID,NULL);
        return;
    }

    strcpy(string1,message.str1);
    strcpy(string2,message.str2);
    //printf("string2: %s\n",messaggio.str2);

    return;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int fd_msg = -1;
    int key_msg = -1;
    pid_t p1;
    pid_t p2;

    key_msg = ftok("../Example/in.txt",55);   
    if((fd_msg = msgget(key_msg,IPC_CREAT | 0770)) == -1){             
        printf("Error creation message queue %d --> %s\n",errno, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    if((p1 = fork()) == 0){
        //child 1 (writer)
        sender(fd_msg);
        exit(0);
    }

    waitpid(p1,NULL,0);

    if((p2 = fork()) == 0){
        //child 2 (reader)
        receiver(fd_msg);
        exit(0);
    }

    waitpid(p2,NULL,0);

    msgctl(fd_msg,IPC_RMID,NULL);      
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send only *one* message and a length of `sizeof(message)-sizeof(long int)` just as you do for receiving the message.  That's because `str1` and `str2` have *fixed* lengths of 255.

You want only *one* message (that sends the data for *both* strings in a single message).

As you have it, the "short" payload length that you [should] send is `255 + 5 + 1` and *not* `5 + 1 + 5 + 1`

There are a number of ways to do this:

1. Send one message with both strings using the full `sizeof(msg)`
2. Send one message with full size of `str1` but short length of `str2`
3. Combine `str1` and `str2` into a single buffer and [manually] concatenate/split the strings
4. Use a single buffer and send two messages, one for each string, using just the short length of each string.

---

**Example #1:**

Here is the corrected code using the full message size:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct {
    long int type;
    char str1[255];
    char str2[255];
} msg;

void
sender(int fd_msg)
{
    msg message;
    char *string1 = "Hello";
    char *string2 = "World";

    strcpy(message.str1, string1);
    strcpy(message.str2, string2);

    size_t len = sizeof(message) - sizeof(long);

    message.type = 1;
    printf("Sending length %zu\n",len);
    if (msgsnd(fd_msg, &message, len, 0) == -1) {
        printf("Error sending message at message 1 queue %d --> %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        return;
    }

    if (printf("Message sent at the queue: %s -- %s\n", message.str1, message.str2) < 0) {
        printf("Error printing sent messages %d --> %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        msgctl(fd_msg, IPC_RMID, NULL);
        return;
    }
    return;
}

void
receiver(int fd_msg)
{
    msg message;
    char string1[255];
    char string2[255];

    sleep(1);

    ssize_t len = msgrcv(fd_msg, &message, sizeof(message) - sizeof(long int), 1, 0);
    if (len == -1) {
        printf("error receiving message type 1 %d --> %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        return;

    }

    printf("Received length: %zu\n",len);
    if (printf("Message received! : %s -- %s\n", message.str1, message.str2) < 0) {
        printf("Error printing received message %d --> %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        msgctl(fd_msg, IPC_RMID, NULL);
        return;
    }

    strcpy(string1, message.str1);
    strcpy(string2, message.str2);
    // printf("string2: %s\n",messaggio.str2);

    return;
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd_msg = -1;
    int key_msg = -1;
    pid_t p1;
    pid_t p2;

    key_msg = ftok("../Example/in.txt", 55);
    if ((fd_msg = msgget(key_msg, IPC_CREAT | 0770)) == -1) {
        printf("Error creation message queue %d --> %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    if ((p1 = fork()) == 0) {
        // child 1 (writer)
        sender(fd_msg);
        exit(0);
    }

    waitpid(p1, NULL, 0);

    if ((p2 = fork()) == 0) {
        // child 2 (reader)
        receiver(fd_msg);
        exit(0);
    }

    waitpid(p2, NULL, 0);

    msgctl(fd_msg, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the program output:

```
Sending length 512
Message sent at the queue: Hello -- World
Received length: 512
Message received! : Hello -- World
```

---

**Example #2:**

Here is the program using a "short" length for `str2`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct {
    long int type;
    char str1[255];
    char str2[255];
} msg;

void
sender(int fd_msg)
{
    msg message;
    char *string1 = "Hello";
    char *string2 = "World";

    strcpy(message.str1, string1);
    strcpy(message.str2, string2);

    size_t len = sizeof(message.str1) + strlen(message.str2) + 1;

    message.type = 1;
    printf("Sending length %zu\n",len);
    if (msgsnd(fd_msg, &message, len, 0) == -1) {
        printf("Error sending message at message 1 queue %d --> %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        return;
    }

    if (printf("Message sent at the queue: %s -- %s\n", message.str1, message.str2) < 0) {
        printf("Error printing sent messages %d --> %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        msgctl(fd_msg, IPC_RMID, NULL);
        return;
    }
    return;
}

void
receiver(int fd_msg)
{
    msg message;
    char string1[255];
    char string2[255];

    sleep(1);

    ssize_t len = msgrcv(fd_msg, &message, sizeof(message) - sizeof(long int), 1, 0);
    if (len == -1) {
        printf("error receiving message type 1 %d --> %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        return;

    }

    printf("Received length: %zu\n",len);
    if (printf("Message received! : %s -- %s\n", message.str1, message.str2) < 0) {
        printf("Error printing received message %d --> %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        msgctl(fd_msg, IPC_RMID, NULL);
        return;
    }

    strcpy(string1, message.str1);
    strcpy(string2, message.str2);
    // printf("string2: %s\n",messaggio.str2);

    return;
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd_msg = -1;
    int key_msg = -1;
    pid_t p1;
    pid_t p2;

    key_msg = ftok("../Example/in.txt", 55);
    if ((fd_msg = msgget(key_msg, IPC_CREAT | 0770)) == -1) {
        printf("Error creation message queue %d --> %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    if ((p1 = fork()) == 0) {
        // child 1 (writer)
        sender(fd_msg);
        exit(0);
    }

    waitpid(p1, NULL, 0);

    if ((p2 = fork()) == 0) {
        // child 2 (reader)
        receiver(fd_msg);
        exit(0);
    }

    waitpid(p2, NULL, 0);

    msgctl(fd_msg, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the program output:

```
Sending length 261
Message sent at the queue: Hello -- World
Received length: 261
Message received! : Hello -- World
```

---

**Example #3:**

Using *separate* `str1` and `str2` forces us to send the full size for `str1` even if the actual string length is less.

To send a *single* message that has *both* strings and sends *only* the length we need would require combining `str1` and `str2` into a *single* buffer (e.g. `strs`). This requires that we concatenate the two strings into the buffer.

This also requires that the receiver recover the two separate strings.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct {
    long int type;
    char strs[512];
} msg;

void
sender(int fd_msg)
{
    msg message;
    char *string1 = "Hello";
    char *string2 = "World";

    char *cp = message.strs;

    strcpy(cp, string1);
    cp += strlen(cp) + 1;

    strcpy(cp, string2);
    cp += strlen(cp) + 1;

    size_t len = cp - message.strs;

    message.type = 1;
    printf("Sending length %zu\n",len);
    if (msgsnd(fd_msg, &message, len, 0) == -1) {
        printf("Error sending message at message 1 queue %d --> %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        return;
    }
}

void
receiver(int fd_msg)
{
    msg message;
    char string1[255];
    char string2[255];

    sleep(1);

    ssize_t len = msgrcv(fd_msg, &message, sizeof(message) - sizeof(long int), 1, 0);
    if (len == -1) {
        printf("error receiving message type 1 %d --> %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        return;

    }

    printf("Received length: %zu\n",len);

    char *cp = message.strs;

    strcpy(string1, cp);
    cp += strlen(cp) + 1;

    strcpy(string2, cp);
    cp += strlen(cp) + 1;

    printf("string1: %s\n",string1);
    printf("string2: %s\n",string2);

    return;
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd_msg = -1;
    int key_msg = -1;
    pid_t p1;
    pid_t p2;

    key_msg = ftok("../Example/in.txt", 55);
    if ((fd_msg = msgget(key_msg, IPC_CREAT | 0770)) == -1) {
        printf("Error creation message queue %d --> %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    if ((p1 = fork()) == 0) {
        // child 1 (writer)
        sender(fd_msg);
        exit(0);
    }

    waitpid(p1, NULL, 0);

    if ((p2 = fork()) == 0) {
        // child 2 (reader)
        receiver(fd_msg);
        exit(0);
    }

    waitpid(p2, NULL, 0);

    msgctl(fd_msg, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the program output:

```
Sending length 12
Received length: 12
string1: Hello
string2: World
```

---

**Example #4:**

I'd probably do example #1 and send the full struct length.

Or, I'd use the combined buffer from example #3, but send *two* separate messages, one for each string:

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct {
    long int type;
    char str[255];
} msg;

void
sendone(int fd_msg,int type,const char *str)
{
    msg message;

    strcpy(message.str, str);
    size_t len = strlen(str) + 1;

    message.type = type;

    printf("Sending type %ld length %zu\n",message.type,len);
    if (msgsnd(fd_msg, &message, len, 0) == -1) {
        printf("Error sending message at message 1 queue %d --> %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        return;
    }

    printf("Message sent at the queue: %s\n", message.str);
}

void
sender(int fd_msg)
{
    char *string1 = "Hello";
    char *string2 = "World";

    sendone(fd_msg,2,string2);
    sendone(fd_msg,1,string1);

    return;
}

ssize_t
recvone(int fd_msg,msg *message)
{
    int type = 0;

    ssize_t len = msgrcv(fd_msg, message, sizeof(msg) - sizeof(long int), type, 0);
    if (len == -1) {
        printf("error receiving message %d --> %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        return len;
    }

    printf("Received type %ld message of length: %zu\n",message->type,len);
    printf("Message received! : %s\n",message->str);

    return len;
}

void
receiver(int fd_msg)
{
    msg message;
    char strings[2][255];

    sleep(1);

    // deliberately receive messages in any order
    for (int imsg = 1;  imsg <= 2;  ++imsg) {
        recvone(fd_msg,&message);
        strcpy(strings[message.type - 1],message.str);
    }

    for (int imsg = 1;  imsg <= 2;  ++imsg)
        printf("receiver: string %d: %s\n",imsg,strings[imsg - 1]);

    return;
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd_msg = -1;
    int key_msg = -1;
    pid_t p1;
    pid_t p2;

    key_msg = ftok("../Example/in.txt", 55);
    if ((fd_msg = msgget(key_msg, IPC_CREAT | 0770)) == -1) {
        printf("Error creation message queue %d --> %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    if ((p1 = fork()) == 0) {
        // child 1 (writer)
        sender(fd_msg);
        exit(0);
    }

    waitpid(p1, NULL, 0);

    if ((p2 = fork()) == 0) {
        // child 2 (reader)
        receiver(fd_msg);
        exit(0);
    }

    waitpid(p2, NULL, 0);

    msgctl(fd_msg, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the program output:

```
Sending type 2 length 6
Message sent at the queue: World
Sending type 1 length 6
Message sent at the queue: Hello
Received type 2 message of length: 6
Message received! : World
Received type 1 message of length: 6
Message received! : Hello
receiver: string 1: Hello
receiver: string 2: World
```